# Bypass error Division by zero when doing a loop - Python

Tags: python

New using Python :) I am trying to normalise my data using different columns however, it sometimes occur that some columns I am using to make division have value = 0. Which then give me error: ZeroDivisionError by zero.

I have one dataframe mergedfs and loop through columns to calculate normalised values.

```
b = 0
w = (len(files))+1 #number depending on how many csv files I have. This will determine which columns index I will use.
while b < len(files):
    b += 1
    if b == 1:
        w += 1
        mergedfs.insert(len(files)+1+b, 'NHAF R{}'.format(b), np.log10((((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106)) / sum(((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106))))))
    else:
         w += 2
         mergedfs.insert(len(files)+1+b, 'NHAF R{}'.format(b), np.log10(((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106)) / sum(((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106)))))
```

The ZeroDivisionError by zero is usually because sometimes. mergedfs.ix[:,b] AND mergedfs.ix[:,b] will be equal to 0.

Is there a way to bypass it?

```
I have tried np.log10((((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106)) / sum(((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106)))).where(mergedfs.ix[:,b] != 0)
```

However, no success.

I have searched for quite a while on stackoverflow and most didn't work on my code.

Thanks a lot if you can guide me a bit to solve this problem.

Cheers !

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you have a 0 as the denominator? You can catch the error using a `try`, but you'll need to supply a replacement value to use.

Comment: Hi @Carcigenicate I just want ti skip if they are equal to zero but I don't want to stop the process

Comment: Catch the exception and indicate what needs to be done in the except block . https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: then, in the except block, pass

Comment: @Flora Do you know how to use `try`?

Answer (score 2):

Imbed the code in `try..except` to catch the exception. Ignore the exception by `pass`

```
try:
   while b < len(files):
    b += 1
    if b == 1:
        w += 1
        mergedfs.insert(len(files)+1+b, 'NHAF R{}'.format(b), np.log10((((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106)) / sum(((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106))))))
    else:
         w += 2
         mergedfs.insert(len(files)+1+b, 'NHAF R{}'.format(b), np.log10(((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106)) / sum(((mergedfs.ix[:,b] / mergedfs.ix[:,w])/106)/((mergedfs.ix[:,b].sum() / (mergedfs.ix[:,w].sum())/106)))))

except ZeroDivisionError as err:
   pass
```

A novel way is to suppress the exception:

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(ZeroDivisionError):
  {your code goes here}
```